# Why won't syndaemon start from /etc/rc5.d?

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, touchpad

I'm trying to start syndaemon during boot so it's available from the login window.  Nothing has worked, so I have evolved a more and more complicated attempt to try to get at what is going on.  Here is where I am at now:

Contents of `/etc/rc5.d/S99syndaemon`:

```
#!/bin/bash

/home/michael/syntest &
```

Contents of `/home/michael/syntest`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "BEGIN" >> /home/michael/synlog
ps aux | grep [s]yndaemon
I=0
while [ "$?" = "1" ]; do
      let I=$I+1
      echo "TRY $I" >> /home/michael/synlog
      syndaemon -d -i 0.5 -R >> /home/michael/synlog2 2>&1
      sleep 1
      ps aux | grep [s]yndaemon
done
ps aux | grep [s]yndaemon >> /home/michael/synlog
echo "END" >> /home/michael/synlog
```

Permissions:

```
ls -l /etc/rc5.d/S99syndaemon /etc/init.d/syndaemon /home/michael/syntest
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  37 Apr 22 20:59 /etc/init.d/syndaemon
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  19 Apr 22 18:24 /etc/rc5.d/S99syndaemon -> ../init.d/syndaemon
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 362 Apr 22 20:54 /home/michael/syntest
```

The log file `/home/michael/synlog` is **not** being created.

I also tried both of these commands, to no effect:

```
sudo update-rc.d syndaemon defaults
sudo service syndaemon start
```

Why won't my script run?  Why isn't synclient being run?

Comment: From "The log file /home/michael/synlog is not being created." I suspect that `/home/michael` is  an encrypted `HOME` directory, If `df $HOME` shows `/home/michael/.Private ...` it is. Therefore, it is not "mounted" until you login. Store your script somewhere else that is mounted when `/etc/rc5.d/*` is run, e.g. a directory you create under `/usr/local` see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: @waltinator HOME is not encrypted.  I tried several other directories too including /dev/shm initially... my guess was it wasn't mounted yet (but so late in rc5.d???) hence my attempt at a loop as well as other directories.